# Why does 'neutral' not normalize to '[]' in the List monoid?

Tags: typeclass, idris, type-level-computation

The following Idris definition typechecks with Idris 1.3.0:

```
foo : (xs : List Nat) -> xs = ([] <+> xs)
foo xs = Refl
```

however, this doesn't:

```
foo : (xs : List Nat) -> xs = (neutral <+> xs)
foo xs = Refl
```

giving the following type error:

```
 When checking right hand side of foo with expected type
         xs = neutral <+> xs

 Type mismatch between
         neutral ++ xs = neutral ++ xs (Type of Refl)
 and
         xs = neutral ++ xs (Expected type)

 Specifically:
         Type mismatch between
                 neutral ++ xs
         and
                 xs
```

Why does `neutral <+> xs` not normalize to `xs` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neutral` will be interpreted as a implicit argument because it's lower case and appears in a type declaration. But you can just specify the module. `:doc neutral` gives me `Prelude.Algebra.neutral`:

```
foo : (xs : List Nat) -> xs = (Algebra.neutral <+> xs)
foo xs = Refl
```

Comment: Aaaargh damn, this is not the first time this misfeature of Idris syntax trips me up...